# VBscript para IP y hostname

Tags: vbscript

buen dia, tengo un script que te muestra ip y hostname de la pc, lo que necesitaria es que ese script sea un exe, y quede ejecutandose siempre en el taskbar

les paso el codigo

```
Set NIC1 =     GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")

For Each Nic in NIC1

    if Nic.IPEnabled then
        StrIP = Nic.IPAddress(0)

        Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        CompName= WshNetwork.Computername

        MsgBox "IP:  "&StrIP & vbNewLine _
            & "Nombre del Equipo:  "&CompName,4160,"Galileo Technologies"

        wscript.quit

    End if
Next
```